# Is the smartmontools daemon running regular health checks?

Tags: debian, monitoring, hard-drive

My server has 2 harddisks. I've installed smartmontools on Debian with `apt-get install smartmontools`, enabled it in /etc/default/smartmontools (start_smartd=yes) and started the daemon (`/etc/init.d/smartmontools start`).

My /etc/smartd.conf contains this:

```
DEVICESCAN -d removable -n standby -m my@email.com -M exec /usr/share/smartmontools/smartd-runner
```

Is the smartmontools now configured to run regular health checks? If so, how do I see when it does that? I don't see any indication in `smartctl -l selftest` of health checks being run regularly; the command only showed the two tests I recently ran manually. I also don't see anything in /var/log/messages that indicates regular health checks are being run.

Answer (score 1):

If it is running them, then they will show up in `-l selftest` and `syslog`. I don't have experience with the `DEVICESCAN` option, you can probably add a `-s` directive on the `DEVICESCAN` line to enable scheduled scanning.

I have my disks individually configured with:

```
/dev/sda -d ata -a -s (S/../.././06|L/../../6/06) -m <email>
```

That does a short test every morning and a long test on Saturdays.

If you add specific configuration for your disks, then comment out the `DEVICESCAN` entry.

Comment: I can also use `-s ...` in combination with DEVICESCAN, right?

Comment: @Hongli I believe so, I just haven't done it myself.

Answer (score 0):

For notifications there is `smart-notifier`.